# Match pattern at the end of string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the below pattern for a string.

[any alphanumeric][0 or more characters][(one or more digits-one or more digits)OR*]

Correct strings -  sensor1-2, s1-2, s*, s_s* 
Incorrect strings - sensor1, s1-, *s1-3

I tried the pattern `^\w.*[(\d+-\d+)\*]$` But it matches strings like sensor1. Any ideas would be helpful. I am planning to use this from C#.

Comment: That dot was wrong. Try this regex: \w*(\d+[\-_]\d+|\\*)

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/WVOT2c/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also remove the square braces and put an or (`|`) inside to match the * case:

```
(\d+-\d+|\*)
```

Editing the existing expression, you get:

```
^\w.*(\d+-\d+|\*)$
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/T4hSo5/2)